# How to append .jpg extension for the images urls when there is no extension?

Tags: php, jquery

I am generating zoom, thumbnail, and preview images for some images. Some images are saved without their extension. When I am displaying in the image gallery, images without extension are not zooming. This is because the lightbox which we are using is expecting a .jpg extension for images. So the images are not zooming when clicking on it. Zooming on images with the  extension are ok.

For this I am appending the .jpg extension like the code below, but it is not working.

```
<?php foreach($images as $line):
    $image_info = pathinfo($line['big']->filename);
    if(!array_key_exists('extension', $image_info))
    {
        $zoom_file = $line['big']->filename."?ext=.jpg";    
    }
    else 
    {
        $zoom_file = $line['big']->filename;
    }

?>

<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $media_cdn.$zoom_file?>"> 
        <img src="<?php echo $media_cdn.$line['normal']->filename ?>"
            width = "200px" alt="image" />
    </a>
</li>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you pointed in the right direction...

```
$image = $from->somewhere;
$ext   = strtolower(end(explode(".", $image)));
$image = ($ext != "jpg") ? $image.".jpg" : $image;
```

*edit*

I don't believe this line is correct:

`$zoom_file = $line['big']->filename."?ext=.jpg";`

Perhaps it should be:

`$zoom_file = $line['big']->filename.".jpg";` ?